# Weird dynamic table bug

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Row:<input id="gRow">Col:<input id="gCol"><button onClick="selectCell()">Find</button>
        <button onClick="addCol(); update();">Add Col</button><br/>
        <button onClick="addRow(); update();">Add Row</button><br/>
        <table id="tab">
            <tr class="rowtitle">
                <td></td>
                <th>1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row row-1">
                <th class="coltitle">1</th>
                <td class="col col-1 edit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            update();
            function update(){
                $('.edit').bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
                }).blur(function() {
                    $(this).attr('contentEditable', false);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
nCol = 1,
nRow = 1;

var addCol = function(){
    nCol++;
    //add nes cols
    $('.rowtitle').append("<th class='title'>"+nCol+"</th>");
    for (var i = 0; i <= nCol; i++) {
        $('.row-'+i).append( "<td class = 'col col-" + i + " edit'></tr>" );
    };

};

var addRow = function(){
    nRow++;
    $("#tab").append( "<tr class = 'row row-" + nRow + "'></tr>" );

    $('.row-'+nRow).append("<th class='coltitle'>"+nRow+"</th>")
    //add nes cols
    for (var i = 1; i <= nCol; i++) {
        $('.row-'+nRow).append( "<td class = 'col col-" + i + " edit'></tr>" );
    };
};

var selectCell = function(){
    var col = $('#gCol').val(),
        row = $('#gRow').val();

    console.log('.row-'+row+' .col-'+col);
    $('.row-'+row+' .col-'+col).css('background-color', 'red');
};
```

When I used selectCell, I noticed it wasn't working. Upon inspection, I noticed the rows were doing what they should, a unique class each time. However, the columns would repeat multiple times within a row. How can I fix this?

To view what is acctually happening, create a bunch of rows and columns. Then type row 3 and col 5. This is what should happen. However, now type 1 and 1.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xmrenvz7/1/)

Comment: Tip: `$(this).attr('contentEditable', true).focus();`

Comment: it's buggy in any case: follow this steps to see the issue: click: four times **Add Row** and than four times **Add Col** http://jsfiddle.net/xmrenvz7/2/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What does the .focus() do? I noticed the bug. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: The `.focus()` sets the blinking caret inside the contenteditable cell. Without it you need to actually click three times to get the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addCol is bugged. It should be:

```
var addCol = function () {
    nCol++;
    //add nes cols
    $('.rowtitle').append("<th class='title'>" + nCol + "</th>");
    $('.row').append("<td class = 'col col-" + nCol + " edit'></tr>");
};
```

Comment: IT's still buggy: click: Four times Add-Row and than four times Add-Col http://jsfiddle.net/xmrenvz7/2/

Comment: Awesome. Another thing I just noticed is that if you click new row twice then column 2 it becomes funky. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just saw that also. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: bleh, you're looping over your rows by counting your columns

Comment: Seemed to have worked. Thanks! @karaokyo I removed the loops.